# Purpose of E-mail from Area 51

Tags: discussion

After I logged into the site this evening, Area 51 sent me the e-mail which I have copied below.  I was wondering if this means that we have graduated from Area 51, or if it is just to thank me for participating.

> Thank you for following through on your commitment to Geographic Information Systems!
>
> In the 120 days since Geographic Information Systems launched, the community has generated 958 questions (906 answered!), 2,635 answers, 1,267 users, and 1,175 views per day.
>
> Please share a link to the site with anyone you think might be interested in our community:
>
> http://gis.stackexchange.com
>
> We hope you continue to visit Geographic Information Systems and help it grow into a vibrant, useful community that benefits the internet at large.
>
> All the best,
>
> The Stack Exchange Team

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, it appears to me that it was just an automatic thank you.  We are still in beta.

Comment: the key phrase is "Thank you for following through on your commitment". A little more info on what commitment means here is at http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq. Basicly all it means is that you've said you will participate, and then you actually did, so they're saying "thank you" :)